# How to run Gant targets from within a Grails controller?

Tags: grails, groovy, gant

Suppose I have a block of Gant code:

```
 target(echo:"test"){
    ant.echo(message:"hi")
 }
 setDefaultTarget("echo")
```

This is usually run from a command line.

How could I place the block in a Grails controller and run it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AntBuilder for this:

```
class FooController {

   def index = {
      def ant = new AntBuilder()
      ant.echo(message:"hi")
   }
}
```

Comment: Dear Burt, thank you for your nice solution.  Does this mean that I cannot simply copy the rich grails scipts to my controllers for use?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a groovy script say DynaScript_.groovy that contains your Gant code and place this script file in the {grailsHome}/scripts folder.

And then you can invoke the script file from your controller like this:

```
class FooController {

     def index = {
           def process  =  "cmd /c grails dyna-script".execute()
           def out = new StringBuilder()
       process.waitForProcessOutput(out, new StringBuilder())
           println "$out" 
     }
}
```

**It's important that your script name ends with an underscore.**